# javascript session alert then redirect

Tags: javascript, session

I have a simple javascript script to alert people to save their work before they are timed out.  I have it set up to give them an alert box after 10 minutes and after 15 minutes (or 5 minutes after the 10) it will give them another alert box and send the home page.

The first alert works, but can't get the 2nd alert to work and redirect.

```
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime();

function startTimer() {
  var timerID = window.setTimeout(sendfirstAlert, 10 * 60 * 1000 );

}

function sendfirstAlert() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var dtay = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3");

  var distance = now - countDownDate;
  alert("Your Session will expire in 5 minutes, please save your work.  It's currently ( " + dtay + ")");
   var sesnow = new Date().getTime();
   var newdistance =  (sesnow - now ) ; 
   var newdistance2 = (newdistance / 60 ) / 1000 ;


if (newdistance2 > 5) {
 window.location = "https://www.hompage.com";
  alert("It has been over 5 minutes since you were alerted. Your session has timed out and you will be redirected to the Home page.");

}
}
```

The page has

startTimer();

UPDATE:  Apparently this works in IE but not fully functional in chrome.  It works in Chrome when I inspect the page , (developer), however, not when I don't use the inspect page option.   (View if normal)

Comment: So you want this reset every time a user performs an action? How is timing out defined?

Comment: Yes.  This is only needed on 2 pages of the site. When they Save/Submit their changes on the page, the timer is reset.  What I'm trying to prevent is someone that walks away from their work and comes back to it and the session has already timed out.    When they hit OK, they will go and save their work and the timer is reset when the page loads again.  If they don't click OK and it times out the 2nd alert will pop up and let them know it's past the session and they are redirected.